# How to fix error when trying to connect database with postgress?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to connect a postgress database using docker on windows 10 with wsl.
But when I try to connect the following error appears: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND database.
How can I solve this problem???

docker-compose

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  database:
    image: postgres
    container_name: localhost
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=docker
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=ignite
      - POSTGRES_DB=rentx
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/data/postgres
    network_mode: host
  app:
    build: .
    container_name: rentx
    ports:
      - 3333:3333
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/app
    network_mode: host

volumes:
  pgdata:
    driver: local
```

```
{
    "type":"postgres",
    "port": 5432,
    "host":"localhost",
    "username":"docker",
    "password":"ignite",
    "database":"rentx"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message you show suggests you're trying to connect to a hostname `database`.  That is probably correct, but inconsistent with the configuration you show.

Your Compose setup specifies `network_mode: host`.  You should almost never need this setting.  It disables Docker's network layer, including normal inter-container communication.  Delete this line from both containers, and then the host name `database` will resolve from the application container.

In the database configuration you show, correspondingly, you need `"host": "database"`, matching the database's service block name in the `docker-compose.yml` file.

You also do not normally need to set `container_name:`.  In particular setting `container_name: localhost` could have some confusing consequences, since the host name `localhost` is usually defined as the special IPv4 address 127.0.0.1 which in Docker usually resolves to the current container.  I'd also delete the `container_name:` settings.

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  database:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports: # optional unless you're connecting from outside Docker
      - 5432:5432
    environment: { unmodified: from original question }
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data # <-- note corrected filesystem path
    # no network_mode: or container_name:
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 3333:3333
    # no network_mode:, container_name:, or volumes:
volumes:
  pgdata: # empty
```